# Can I place my ggplot2 legend right beside the horizontal axis label?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

In order to save as much as white space as I can, I would like to place the legend entry at the same height as the horizontal axis label. Can this be done and if so, how?

Here's a plot illustrating what I am hoping to achieve, with current and hoped-for legend position illustrated using a (manually added) green box.

[image]

I currently place the legend using `theme(legend.position=c(0.87,0.1))` (noting that the exact coordinates are not relevant). Ideally, this route would allow for values outside of the [0,1] domain but it appears not to allow for that.

`theme(legend.position="bottom")` places the legend well outside of the plotting area, thus taking up more white space than I am willing to spare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just might have to play around with negative values regarding the y-coordinates of your legend.position-vector.
Here's an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, color=Species))+
  geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(~Species)+
  theme(legend.position=c(0.87,-0.01))
```

Note the `-0.01` value. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes. Initially, I had set a negative value and noted that that didn't work. However, I now realise that my negative value was large enough for the legend to be plotted outside of the canvas altogether.

Comment: Another reason I'm delighted that this works: I find myself in an office full of Python users. Some of these used the question to once more try and convince me I should move to Python. "In Python, this is easy." Yeah, in R, too!

Comment: Of course, Python has some easy workflows too. However, when it comes to statistical programming I'm preferring R.